# Probability for the minimal polynomial to be equal to the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, probability-distributions, minimal-polynomials

Consider the space $M_n(\mathbb R)$ of real square matrices of dimension $n$.

Is there *a way* to define the probability for the minimal polynomial to be equal to the characteristic polynomial? By *a way*, I mean using probability density functions that are classical on $M_n(\mathbb R)$.

If so, what is the desired probability value (depending on $n$)? Should be one for $n=1$!

Comment: I'd expect this to be $1$ under any reasonable *way*, since the set of matrices for which the polynomials differ has one less degree of freedom than the full set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and  $A=[a_{i,j}]\in M_n(K)$ be a generic matrix. Then the disciminant $D((a_{i,j}))=discrim(\det(A-xI_n),x)$ is a non-zero element of the ring $R=K[(a_{i,j})]$. $Z=\{(a_{i,j})|D((a_{i,j}))=0\}$ is Zariski closed and its complement $C$ is an open dense set (in the Zariski topology sense). If $K=\mathbb{C}$, then $Z$ has Lebesgue measure $0$; let $P$ be a probability over $K^{n^2}$ that is associated to a measurable density function.
; then $P(Z)=0$ and $P(C)=1$. Let $U=\{A\in M_n|A$ is cyclic$\}$; note that $D((a_{i,j}))\not= 0$ implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct and $A$ is cyclic; thus $C\subset U$ and $P(U)\geq P(C)=1$.